# Python list referencing itself - how does it work?

Tags: python, list

When I use = operator in python, python creates an object for me (if it doesn't exist), and then links my variable to it. So

```
>>>a = 1
>>>b = a
>>>a = 2
>>>print(f'{a}, {b}') 
2, 1
```

seem to be ok. For mutable objects, when I change an object, pointers still point to the same object, so this is ok too:

```
>>>a = []
>>>b = a
>>>a = a.append(1)
>>>print(f'{a}, {b}') 
[1], [1]
```

Now what if I will do that thing:

```
>>>a = [1]
>>>a[0] = a
>>>print(f'{a}')
```

what I was expecting is infinite links so this should provide some error, but python handling it normally, describing a as [[...]]. Now I can access object of any deepness a[0][0][0][0][0] and it still would be [[...]]. Actually [1] should be somewhere in memory, but I'm unable to access it.

Okay, what will happen if I would make this thing now:

```
>>>a[0][0][0] = 5
```

I would expect that a becomes either [[[5]]] or it will become 5 by itself (strange but I could say it has some sense).
Actually, no. a becomes [5].

Could anyone explain why? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `a[0] = a` then `a` is a reference to a list whose first element is `a` itself. Something like

```
 a --+--> [ X ]
     ^      |
     |      |
     +------+
```

Therefore `(a[0])[0][0]=5` simplify to `a[0][0]=5` since `a[0]=a` which in turns simplify to `a[0]=5` but not to `a = 5`.

Note that there is no infinite list involved here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what's happening with annotations<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
a = [1]    # Creates list object containing 1 and binds a to it.
a[0] = a   # Changes the first element of that list to bind to a itself.
```

At that point, `a[0]`, `a[0][0]`, and all others like it, reference the first element of the list, which is `a`. It is a self-referential binding so will follow itself to itself as many times as you wish. Douglas Hofstadter would be proud :-)

So, now when you do `a[0][0][0][0][0] = 5`, it's no different to doing `a[0] = 5` and that is indeed what you get:

```
>>> a[0][0][0][0] = 5
>>> a
[5]
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This object and binding behaviour, when Python developers first grok it, is a real eye-opener and introduces them to the beauty of the underlying mechanics of the language :-) It was a real epiphany for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you've created the infinite list/reference loop with

```
a = [1]
a[0] = a
```

You've created a list where the first entry in every list simply references the same object.

```
id(a)
Out[17]: 4717321984
id(a[0])
Out[18]: 4717321984
id(a[0][0])
Out[19]: 4717321984
id(a[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0])
Out[21]: 4717321984
etc.
```

As soon as you change it:

```
a[0][0][0][0][0] = 5
```

You are breaking the reference loop by setting that list element to a link to the object representing integer 5. As every iteration was just the same object ID, you now have:

```
a
Out[26]: [5]
id(a)
Out[27]: 4717321984
id(a[0])
Out[28]: 4440245504
id(5)
Out[29]: 4440245504
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly when you make that:

```
>>>a = [1] ## a[0] is equal to 1
>>>a[0] = a ## a[0] is not equal to 1. There is no 1 in a anymore
```

It is normal that you cant access `1`. It is like that:

```
>>>a = [1] ## a[0] is equal to 1
>>>a[0] = 2 ## a[0] is not equal to 1 , equal to 2. There is no 1 in a anymore
```

And if you look carefully:

```
>>>a[0][0][0] = 5
```

Is same with:

```
>>>a[0] = 5
```

Becasue `a[0][0][0]` is equal to `a` and `a[0]`.

```
>>>a[0][0][0] == a == a[0]
True
```

So five is being first component of `a`.

And yes because of `a[0][0][0]` is equal to `a` you expected that `a` was being equal to `5`. But notice that `a[0]` is only reference for `a`, it is not `a` **really**, it is pointer of `a` **(I know `id(a)` is equal to `id(a[0])` but that just means that memory address of `a`, and reference of pointer of `a[0]` is same)**. You can change value of any pointer to another memory address. It dont change content of first reference address of pointer.